# Difference between @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest and vue-jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

What is the difference between these two packages:

- `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest`
- `vue-jest`

If I have one is the other unnecessary? If so, when should one use one or the other?

Comment: The CLI plugin dependes on `vue-jest` itself.

Comment: Interesting, just saw a ```package.json``` that omits ```vue-jest``` but has the CLI plugin. Of course, it is not actually running any unit tests.

Comment: You don't need to include it in `package.json` yourself, it's in the plugin's `package.json`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest (see dependencies tab or look at the file on GitHub).

Comment: Ah okay got it. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Jest is JS testing framework and understands only JS.

So [vue-jest](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest) is used to transform the SFC(.vue) file to a format understandable by jest. Its job ends there.

On the other hand, [@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest) is the webpack type plugin that does more things in addition to just transforming the code and has deeper level integration with vue cli. It internally uses vue-jest to achieve some level of functionality.

Capabilities of [@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest) includes

- Transforms your vue files to JS to be feed to jest.
- creating a boilerplate jest setup with example tests when installed.
- Adding all the eslint and package dependencies.
- providing wrappers to run the jest tests which provide specific hints to babel to avoid build issues.

Comment: 3 years on and the fragility of the many dependencies of cli-plugin-unit-jest has given me no choice but to remove it from a project.

Comment: vue test utils are the way to go